# MongoDB - GeoJSON - Find document inside a radius

Tags: mongodb, latitude-longitude, geojson

Thank to a previous computation I have the coordinate of the center of a town that was query previously : `[lon, lat]`. I have another parameter in the query `radius`. I want to find every documents in my db inside this virtual cercle.

My schema :

```
const artisanSchema = new Schema ({
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  name: { type: String, index: true },
  address: {
    street: String,
    zip: { type: String, index: true },
    town: { type: String, index: true }
  },
  contact: {
    tel: String,
    mail: String,
    web: String
  },
  activities: [String],
  type: String,
  geometry: mongoose.Schema.Types.Point, //"geometry": {"coordinates":[0.704378,45.194518],"type": "Point"
}
  tagMetier: [Number]
});
```

I try a query like this :

```
Artisan.
  find ({
    'tagMetier': tag,
    'geometry': { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [ myTown.longitude, myTown.latitude ], rad ] } }
  },
  function (err, artisan) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else {
      res.send(artisan);
    }
  })
  .limit(10)
```

If I target my own town with a radius of 5km I got answers with town like 200km or more from where I live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb me,

`rad` is not in metrics unit like kilometers, but in radian because the earth is an unperfect spheroid (so we simplify by calculating it as a big ball).

If I want the result in kilometers I have to do : `rad/6378.1`
In miles : `rad/3963.2`

So finally I wrote : `geometry': { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [ myTown.longitude, myTown.latitude ], rad/6378.1 ] } }`

Voila.

Answer (score 0):

**First Create index**

either you can ensure index on `moongose schema level` or direct on `Mongodb` Collection

in Mongo DB like this

```
db.Artisan.createIndex( { geometry : "2dsphere" } )
```

Or in moongse Scehema Level

```
 geometry: mongoose.Schema.Types.Point, index: "2dsphere"
```

**Now Query**

```
  Artisan.find({ location:
   { $geoWithin:
      { $centerSphere: [ [ myTown.longitude, myTown.latitude ], 5 / 3963.2 ] } } ,'tagMetier': tag})
```

Assuming You radius is in radian
The following will find all Artisan within five miles

**Or**

You can use  `$maxDistance` which consider as `meter`

```
var METERS_PER_MILE = 1609.34
Artisan.find({ location: { $nearSphere: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ myTown.longitude, myTown.latitude ] }, $maxDistance: rad * METERS_PER_MILE } } })
```

For More Information check this 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/geospatial-tutorial/

Comment: That's what happend when you sleep only 2hrs because of a coding rush, you can read too fast the documentation.

The 2nd parameter unit is not kilometer (i'm french btw, so I won't use imperial system ;) ). So I have to calculate the radian like this `rad/6378.1`